# Vote to Reopen Prompt Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-reopen, review-queue

*If any help, I'm using Google Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit) on a Mac.*

When I nominate a question to be reopened, the prompt window is still present after I click "Reopen". The queue moves on to the next question, but the prompt is still there. Clicking "Reopen" again shows the error "You've already voted to reopen this question", and clicking "Cancel" simply closes the window.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Enter "Reopen Votes" queue
2. Vote to Reopen a question
3. Click "Reopen" when the prompt appears
4. Observe bug described above

I'm posting it here on Code Review Meta because I'm unsure if this is consistent across all Stack Exchange sites, or just here.

Comment: I have the same problem on Mac with Safari 12.1.2 (14607.3.9)

Comment: This looks like it might be related to the popup that is shown when reopening. Could I trouble you to go to the question directly (via 'link' in the right sidebar) and try from there? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338097/new-dialog-box-in-reopen-votes-review-queue-doesnt-close

Comment: Confirmed on Firefox/X11 68.2.0esr.  Also seen on [so], and it makes no difference whether the reopen is done by pressing Enter or by mouse-click.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it affects all sites, and should be migrated to [meta.se].

Comment: Present on SO, too.

Comment: I have the same problem with Firefox on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been appearing network wide. Apparently Adam Lear [pushed a fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339182/222299) that should be going into production with "the next build". As such I'm marking this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)